# How many forms of Vivilion are there?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

In Pokemon X and Y, a new Pokemon called Vivillion was released. It is a butterfly, but the interesting part about it is its patterns. It seems like for each region, it has a different pattern. How many are there that can be obtained? I want to collect all of them for fun.

Comment: No research effort at all.

Answer (score 1):

There are [18 Vivillon forms](http://www.serebii.net/pokedex-xy/666.shtml) currently obtainable in-game, and yes, they are region-specific. You can get some help with your Vivillon collection by going to the subreddit, [Vivillon Exchange](http://www.reddit.com/r/VivillonExchange).